# Can Mishloach Manot count as Matanot Laevyonim and vice versa?

Tags: mitzvah, purim, tzedakah-charity

If I donate ready to eat food to a soup kitchen, or, even more directly, if I see 2 homeless men on the street on Purim and hand them each a sandwich and a drink, can that fulfill my obligation to give Mishloach Manot of food to another person AND a gift to the poor?

The Mishna Berurah (694:2) writes " ורשאי ליתן מאכל או מעות" but he doesn't make it clear (to me) whether that would be counted as both obligations (or only one or the other). He also seems to say that if I give food that is from my se'udah, that counts (but for which?) and the [Sha'arei Teshuva](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.694.1?lang=en&with=Sha'arei%20Teshuvah&lang2=en) speaks of giving either 3 eggs' worth of bread or the money to buy 3 eggs' worth of food

> שאם נותן מעות צריך שיתן שיעור שיקנה ג' ביצים אוכל ואם נותן אוכלים צריך שיתן לו שיעור ג' ביצים מפת

Can 2 obligations be fulfilled through the single action here?

Answer (score 5):

The Biur Halacha [695:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.695.4?lang=bi&p2=Biur_Halacha.696.1&lang2=bi) brings this question and quotes Rabbi Akiva Eiger. Rabbi Akiva Eiger qoutes the Turei Even on Megillah 7b which addresses this exact question. It seems like it can go both ways, but no definitive ruling is given.

With regards to *chavilos chavilos* the Rivevos Ephraim 2:193 explains how there is no issue with *chavilos chavilos* by Mishloach Manos and Matonas La'Evyonim since the gemara is *mashma* that it can be done at same time, according to the girsa that says he was yotzeh both MM and ML. He explains that by *bein adom L'Makom* there is an issue of *chavilos chavilos*, but by *ben adam l'chaveiro* there isn't an issue.

Text of Biur Halacha:

> של מיני אוכלים וכו':    בטורי אבן מסתפק אם שלח ב' מנות לאיש עני אם יוכל לחשבם לתרתי לקיום שילוח מנות דגם העני בכלל איש לרעהו ולקיים מתנות לאביונים ואם נתן עוד מתנה א' לעני אחד יצא או לא והביאו הגרע"א בחידושיו.

Answer (score 2):

Meseches Megillah (7a-b)

> רבי יהודה נשיאה שדר ליה לרבי אושעיא אטמא דעיגלא תלתא וגרבא דחמרא שלח ליה קיימת בנו רבינו ומשלוח מנות איש לרעהו ומתנות לאביונים
>
> Rav Yehuda the nasi gave Rav Osha’ya a leg of a calf and a barrel of wine. Rav Osha’ya sent him: you have fulfilled through us the mitzva of Matanot le’evyonim and Mishloach Manot.
> The Haga’os haBach, however, erases the words ‘umatanos le’evyonim, because one object can’t fulfill two mitzvos.